# Windows Phone App: Is there a way to have a button start dialing a phone number from my app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, phone-call

I am creating an app, and I want to have a button that I can click that will dial a phone number. The phone number will already be chosen by me. Is this possible?

Comment: _Is this possible?_ Did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that, using a [`PhoneCallTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394025%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

```
var phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();    
phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = "123456789";    
phoneCallTask.Show();
```

Just put that code in your button's event handler.